# What are the steps for building app using Opentok API?

Tags: android, voip, opentok

I have a project to build an android app for voice calling app. The team has finished the backend functionalities. They purchased Tokbox's Opentok API and provided it to me. I have searched through several sites and I have no clear understanding about Opentok. I want to know the steps to build the android app using Opentok.

> I need to create an SDK first which needs to be injected with an android UI later

Answer (score 1):

Manik here from the OpenTok team.

Please take a look at the following resources on how to add OpenTok to Android applications.

- [OpenTok Android Developer Center](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/android/)
- [OpenTok Android Sample applications](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk-samples)

Both of the links have resources such as the API reference, developer guides, tutorials, and sample applications.

Comment: I have already look into that tutorials but it is for video chat right? I need the steps to create Voice call

Comment: Creating an SDK is much different than creating an application - it's not really something that I can help with over stack overflow. To create a voice only call, simply set the videoTrack property of the publisher instance to false. Doing so will make it audio-only.